# Drag and Drop Orientated CMS for an Intranet?

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system, active-directory, customization, intranet

I'm looking for a Drag & Drop orientated Content Management System for use as an Intranet site.

Also required is CAS integration for Active Directory support. Basically I want AD users to get different Intranet pages based on the GP group.

I would also like for them to be able to customize their homescreen, by adding/removing blocks/widgets.

Do you know of a good open-source CMS for this task?

Comment: Currently testing Drupal 7 with http://drupal.org/project/user_dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[uPortal](http://www.jasig.org/uportal)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ImpressPages drag & drop CMS](http://www.impresspages.org)

Comment: Thanks, but I find the widget collection to be lacking in choices.

Comment: You will be able to add our own widget in 1.1 version http://www.impresspages.org/news/impresspages-1-1-timeline/